# Many-to-Many: Simple vs Rich in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, many-to-many, associations

I have a question about these two relationships as I think I'm overthinking it and have confused myself quite a bit.

So they both involve a new table that sits in between the two tables you want to join.

A simple M2M gets the foreign keys from the other two tables (so example would be "blog_posts_categories" table would get the blog_post_id and the category_id foreign keys). Then for the associations, the blog_post and category models would have has_and_belongs_to_many associations with each other but the joined table gets no model.

for a rich M2M, a third joined table is created. This table gets the foreign key from the other two tables, and those two tables get the foreign key of the joined table. Then for the rails association, the joined DOES get a model, and it `belongs_to` the other two corresponding models. And those two models `has_many` of the joined table model

Am I anywhere near close to being right? I think my issue is that I keep conflating the table with the model or at least for the simple many-to-many since I keep expecting there should be a model to go along with the table.

Thanks for any direction that can be given.

Comment: Did you read the [Rails Guide article on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conceptual understanding of the two are almost there. Rather than thinking of them as *simple* vs. *rich*, I prefer to think of them as *implicit* vs. *explicit*.

Take for example, two models, `Book` and `Author`.

With a `has_and_belongs_to_many`, Rails will implicitly create a *join table* between your two models. I.e. `books_authors`.

You can also explicitly create the join table, say, `Authorship`, that `belongs_to` both. (`Book` and `Author` will then have `has_many :authorships`.)

In both cases, your domain model will look the same:

```
Book (1)--(n) Authorship (n)--(1) Author
```

Now, here is the opninionated part. I prefer to use the explicit approach, as this is easier to grasp, conceptually, and makes it easier to add additional fields to your join table. Say that for example you want the `Authorship` to be ordered, you can easily add an `order` column to your `Authorship` model and use that accordingly.

Comment: @Dremmi thanks this makes sense. When we learned the rich variant (explicit) I really didn't understand the need for the implicit model at that point, it seems that the implicit model would be limited if you need to add more columns. I definitely feel explicit (rich) is easier to grasp, probably not the best habit to pick up but I figure it's easier because the joined table (in your example `authorship` gets a model as well

Is there any scenario in which implicit would be preferred to explicit?

Comment: @BronzeTax: So far I have never come across a situation where I would have preferred the implicit (simple) model. The longer I work, the more I come to appreciate clarity as one of the most important qualities of a codebase.

Comment: @Dremmi I see, well thanks for sharing your knowledge. It's definitely helped clarify these two relationship types.

Answer (score 1):

A third relationship table is suitable for many-to-many relations. You can do something like this:

```
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blog_post_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :blog_post_categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blog_post_categories
  has_many :blog_posts, through: :blog_post_categories
end

class BlogPostCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog_post
  belongs_to :category
end
```

The third model is very simple and its overhead is basically negligible. Also it is flexible and extensive if you want to attach more information to that relationship (for example, priority or timestamp). I personally prefer having a standalone table for relationships rather than a few more columns in the `blog_posts` table.

Here is a relevant blog post: [Why You Don’t Need Has_and_belongs_to_many Relationships](http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/).

Perhaps you can explain the tradeoffs you're considering here?

Comment: sorry I should have clarified, I wasn't contemplating between the two approaches, I just made an example up for the sake of this post to see if I was on the right track with my understanding as I had been questioning myself on if I understood any of it. 

Thanks for that link, haven't had time to dive in at the moment, but bookmarked it for future reading.
@franklsf95

Comment: The article does explain well the pros and cons of `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships. Glad I'm of help.